# Material UI Divider Thickness

Tags: css, material-ui, attributes, styling, divider

I'm looking for a solution to increase the Material UI `Divider` line thickness (stretching horizontal lines vertically or stretching vertical lines horizontally).

I've read the documentation of Material UI v5 at https://mui.com/material-ui/api/divider/.

According to the API, there isn't an attribute to modify the Divider "Thickness".

I've tried different implementations of inline styles (specific to Material UI v5):

```
<Divider sx={{height:"15px", fontSize:"50px", width:"50px", fontWeight:"bold", padding:"15px"}}/>
```

None of the mentioned attributes modified the "thickness" of the line.

**I'm looking for a solution specific to the Material UI v5 Divider component. I don't want to create a Box component and then implement inline sx attributes or custom classes for that Box component.**

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change the CSS property `border-bottom-width` to modify the thiccness of the `Divider`:

```
<Divider sx={{ borderBottomWidth: 5 }} />
```

For vertical `Divider`:

```
<Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem sx={{ borderRightWidth: 5 }} />
```

`styled()` can also be used to create an enhanced version of `Divider` that supports a custom thiccness:

```
const MyDivider = styled(Divider)(({ thiccness, orientation }) => ({
  ...(thiccness !== undefined &&
    (orientation === "vertical"
      ? { borderRightWidth: thiccness }
      : { borderBottomWidth: thiccness }))
}));
```

```
<MyDivider thiccness={10} />
```

```
<MyDivider orientation="vertical" flexItem thiccness={10} />
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Is there also a way to change the thickness and color when using Dividers with text? 

<Divider sx={{ borderColor: 'primary.main', borderBottomWidth: 5}}>
  Text
</Divider>

Comment: e.g. Thickness & color change.  sx={{ m: 4, borderBottomWidth:'4px', background: 'purple' }} For thickness any  padding property works (e.g. pb, pt)

Comment: @ErikMetz Yes, you can do the following: '&.MuiDivider-root': { '&::after': { borderTop: '30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)', }, }.

Answer (score 4):

Thats a real thicc boi

```
<Divider sx={{ borderBottomWidth: '45px' }} />
```